# How can I access boolean variable from Html or ts file into scss?

Tags: angular, sass

I have `changes` variable which is boolean in component.ts file. This variable is also used in `.html` file. I am trying to access this variable in .scss file and based on boolean condition if true, the mobile properties should be applied on the website. How can I access this boolean variable in scss file and apply to &.Mobile and ensure changes function properly with editable template?

Here is my .html file

```
    <div class="ab-table-filters">
```

Here is my scss file

```
.bot {
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;

  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    display: none;
  }
}
      .open {
        ul {
          position: relative;
          top: auto;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .ab-table-filter {
    border-radius: 2px;


    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      display: none;
    }

    &.disabled {
      opacity: .4;
      pointer-events: none;

      &:hover {
        cursor: no-drop;
      }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can't.

Instead you can bind the CSS/SCSS class into template depending on the variable's value in HTML Element, for example -

```
<div [ngClass]="{'ab-table-filters':true, 'css-class': changes }">
```

Here I am added both combination, class which is always applied by default and Dynamic CSS class, Hope this helps.

Update -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use NgClass, I have to refactor my code to not use Ngclass and make sure functionality remains same

Comment: Oh that is different problem then, But this is I believe is the cleanest and easiest way to do this.

Comment: How can I make use of media query to achieve this without use of variable?

Comment: You can set condition on screen width using media query and change styles accordingly.

Comment: I basically have to set property for mobile when max width is 768 px. But in scss how can I use the logic for this?

Comment: So there are 3 drop down tabs in horizontal line, .ab-table-filter is class applied to them. At around 989px they are combining as 1 tab but drop down is not working. Any idea why?